# Как это перевести на C#?

Tags: c#, php

есть код на php

```
$words=Array();

// Заполнить звенья 
for($i=0; $i<count($tmp); $i++) { 
    if ($tmp[$i+1]!='') { 
        $words[$tmp[$i]][]=$tmp[$i+1]; 
        $words[$tmp[$i]]=array_unique($words[$tmp[$i]]); 
    } 
}
```

где tmp это массив со словами.

Очень нужно перевести это дело на C#...

Comment: > Очень нужно перевести это дело на
> C#...

так учите c#, с чего я тебе должен помогать, если ты да же основ не знаешь?

Comment: ок, спрошу конкретней.
warning(не знаю php*)

Почему мы объявили ворд простым массивом, но можем обращаться к нему как к двумерному?

Comment: Для начала вам сюда http://php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?array

Comment: @SOUR, вообще, этот код - бред. PHP должен выдавать ахтунг обращение как к двумерному, а то, что внутри циклы, вообще под наркотой писалось, бессмысленно и беспощадно.

Comment: Покурили с коллегой код. Тут получается на выход массив с уникальными значениями из $tmp. Наркой и не пахнет. Тяжело для моментального понимания. По факту если, как сказан в условии, входит стринг "слово", то на выход будет массив уникальных букв из этого стринга, т.е. 0=>с,1=>л,2=>о,3=>в.
Сорри, с сишарпом не помогу :(

Comment: Упс, ошибся. Но суть не меняется. Это алгоритм получения уникальных значений из входящего массива.

Comment: @zenith, например $tmp[$i] = 'foo', $tmp[$i+1] = 'bar'

    if ($tmp[$i+1]!='')
    // Warning: Undefined index ...    
    $words[$tmp[$i]][]=$tmp[$i+1];
    // добавить в массив NULL (lol) 'bar' (строку!!!); PHP: Warning: ...; и даже если это отработает, 
    $words[$tmp[$i]]=array_unique($words[$tmp[$i]]);
    // $words['foo'] = array_unique(array('bar'))

Итого из массива $tmp = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') :

    $words = array(
      'a' => array('b'),
      'b' => array('c'),
      'c' => array('d')
    );

Разве не наркота?)

Comment: Наверное больше не буду гонять код в голове без теста. Согласен получается бред. Но это уже надо спросить у автора. Лично мне выход напомнил поинтеры из паскаля. Может это какая-то сортировка?

Comment: Это относится к "генератором текста на основе цепей Маркова", вот отсюда кусок вырвал http://www.manhunter.ru/webmaster/358_generator_teksta_na_osnove_cepey_markova.html

Comment: Не наркота, просто быдлокод.

> `if ($tmp[$i+1]!='')`

Автор видимо изобретал `isset($tmp[$i+1])`

> `$words[$tmp[$i]][]=$tmp[$i+1];`

А вот это [штатный способ работы с многомерными массивами](http://php.net/array#example-94). Т.ч. тут даже без нотиса будет работать.

> `$words[$tmp[$i]]=array_unique($words[$tmp[$i]]);`

Тоже популярный говнокод: избыточная ресурсоемкая операция внутри в цикла. Правильно было бы так:

    foreach ($tmp as $i => $w) {
        if (isset($tmp[$i + 1])) {
            $words[$w][] = $tmp[$i + 1]; 
        }
    }

    $words = array_map("array_unique", $words)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, пардон, не нашел по ссылке. Однако `<? $a = array(); $a[5][] = 6; ?>` ничего не выдало. PHP все-таки фригидная истеричка - молчит когда надо и кричит когда не надо =/

Comment: @Sh4dow, пардон, явно там про это не написано. Но тем не менее это работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишу сюда нормальный код на php

```
$words = array();
for ($n = 0; $n < count($tmp)-1; $n++) { // идем по всем словам, кроме последнего
  $w1 = $tmp[$n];   // это и следующее
  $w2 = $tmp[$n+1]; // только для наглядности
  if (!is_array($words[$w1]))      // если массива тут еще нет, 
    $words[$w1] = array();         //   создаем
  if (!in_array($w2, $words[$w1])) // если слова еще нет в списке, 
    $words[$w1][] = $w2;           //   добавляем
}
?><pre><?
print_r($words); // любуемся
?></pre><?
```

На примере по [ссылке](http://www.manhunter.ru/webmaster/358_generator_teksta_na_osnove_cepey_markova.html) выдает такой результат

```
Array
(
    [ИЗ-ЗА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЛЕСА
            [1] => ГОР

    [ЛЕСА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ИЗ-ЗА
        )
    [ГОР] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЕДЕТ
        )
    [ЕДЕТ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ДЕДУШКА
        )
    [ДЕДУШКА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЕГОР
        )
    [ЕГОР] => Array
        (
            [0] => САМ
        )
    [САМ] => Array
        (
            [0] => НА
        )
    [НА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЛОШАДКЕ
            [1] => КОРОВКЕ
            [2] => ТЕЛЯТКАХ
            [3] => КОЗЛЯТКАХ
        )
    [ЛОШАДКЕ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЖЕНА
        )
    [ЖЕНА] => Array
        (
            [0] => НА
        )
    [КОРОВКЕ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ДЕТИ
        )
    [ДЕТИ] => Array
        (
            [0] => НА
        )
    [ТЕЛЯТКАХ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ВНУКИ
        )
    [ВНУКИ] => Array
        (
            [0] => НА
        )
)
```

Передаю эстафету сишарперам :)

ЗЫ: перевел в uppercase, ибо в php ключи чувствительны к регистру, "Из-за" != "из-за"

Comment: Спасибо за разжовывание!
Это я уже спокойно в шарп переведу.

p.s. Плюсану в будущем :)

Comment: Ради спортивного интереса. Так бы это на питоне выглядело:

    words = defaultdict(set)
    for cur, prev in zip(tmp[:-1], tmp[1:]):
        words[prev].add(cur)

Comment: Решение на шарпе :)

     var hTable = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                string w1 = str[i];
                string w2 = str[i+1];
                if (hTable.ContainsKey(w1)==false)
                    hTable[w1] = new Dictionary<int, string>();

                if (hTable[w1].ContainsValue(w2)==false)
                    hTable[w1].Add(i,w2);
            }

Comment: А зачем в качестве значения `Dictionary<int, string>`? Достаточно было бы `StringCollection`. Или еще лучше использовать `HashSet<string>`, это должно быть быстрее и не понадобится проверка `ContainsValue()`:

    var dic = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (dic.TryGetValue(str[i], out hashSet))
        {
            hashSet.Add(str[i+1]);
        }
        else
        {
            dic[str[i]] = new HashSet<string>({ str[i+1] });
        }
    }

И еще для переменной `str` больше подошел бы `LinkedList<string>`

Comment: Лабу уже сдал, но на будущее учту, спасибо :)